# "Locate features along routes" tool and line features - how to use XY tolerance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing

I am trying to use the "locate features along routes" tool to map guardrails to a route, but I'm seeing some very strange behavior.  As a test case, I'm selecting a single guardrail (pictured) that is about 8 meters from the route.

If I set the XY tolerance to 5m, it works perfectly and gives me a single record in the resulting event table with a from and to measure.  But if I set the XY tolerance to 10m, the resulting event table is empty.  The docs say this is a cluster tolerance when line features are used, so why would 5m work but 10m not?  I've tried several values:

2m = doesn't work

3m = works

4m = works

5m = works

6m = works

7m = doesn't work

10m = doesn't work

What is causing this?  I'm trying to process thousands of records so playing with each individual guardrail's XY tolerance is not going to work.

[image]

Comment: Are you two datasets in different coordinate systems?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and could not find any official solutions from ESRI.

Anyway, I don't really know what the problem is, but my method involves converting all linear features into POINTS by finding the intersection points between the route and the linear features. Then I use the "LOCATE_FEATURES_ALONG_ROUTE" on the intersection points.

NOTE: Check if ArcGIS outputs the intersection points as MULTIPOINT. If so, convert them to SINGLEPART before applying the "LOCATE_FEATURES_ALONG_ROUTE" tool.